# Tinymce editor is not showing anymore in bigcommerace

Tags: javascript, php, html, product, bigcommerce

Since sometime my tinymce editor is not showing anymore in bigcommerace. When i try to look for error in console this error is displayed.

http://prntscr.com/q45m6t

Waiting for your kind response

Answer (score 0):

If you've checked to make sure the WYSIWIG is enabled in the Store Settings ([you can find the steps in the last FAQ here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Using-the-WYSIWYG-Editor#faq)), I recommend reaching out to the [BigCommerce Technical Support team via live chat, email, or phone here](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact) to report this as a bug.